# I made PIVOT and JOIN

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Cus table:

```
+----+-------------------------+------+
| ID |          Name           | Age  |
+----+-------------------------+------+
|  1 | Japhet                  | 22   |
|  2 | Abegail                 | 31   |
|  3 | Norlee                  | 35   |
|  4 | Pacita                  | 60   |
|  5 | Reynaldo                | 65   |
|  6 | Barro, Reynaldo Batucan | 65   |
|  7 | Batucan, Japhet C.      | NULL |
|  8 | Barro, Reynaldo B.      | NULL |
+----+-------------------------+------+
```

Cus2 table: (Cus and Cus2 has one to many relationship)

```
+-----+------+-----------------+---------------+
| QID |  ID  |      Name       |    Country    |
+-----+------+-----------------+---------------+
|   1 | 1    | Japhet          |               |
|     | PH   |                 |               |
|   2 | 1    | NULL            | CN            |
|   3 | 1    | Japhet          | PH            |
|   4 | 1    | Japhet          | PH            |
|   5 | 2    | NULL            | PH            |
|   6 | 2    | NULL            | CN            |
|   7 | 2    | John Hammond    | United States |
|   8 | 3    | Mudassar Khan   | India         |
|   9 | 3    | Suzanne Mathews | France        |
|  11 | 4    | Japhe           | PH            |
|  12 | 4    | Abegail         |               |
|     | PH   |                 |               |
|  13 | 4    | Abegail         |               |
|     | US   |                 |               |
|  14 | 3    | LOL             |               |
|     | UK   |                 |               |
|  15 | 4    | Japhet          |               |
|     | PH   |                 |               |
|  16 | 3    | Abegail         |               |
|     |      |                 |               |
|  17 | 2    | Japhet          |               |
|     | FR   |                 |               |
|  18 | 1    | Japhet          | PH            |
|  19 | 4    | Japhet          | PH            |
|  20 | 3    |                 | NULL          |
|  21 | 2    | Abegail         | CN            |
|  22 | 1    | Japhet          | PH            |
|  23 | 5    | Japhet          | USA           |
|  24 | 5    | Abegail         | CN            |
|  25 | 5    | Japhet          | PH            |
|  26 | NULL | NULL            | NULL          |
|  27 | NULL | NULL            | NULL          |
|  28 | NULL | NULL            | NULL          |
|  29 | 8    | Japhet          | PH            |
|  30 | 7    | Abegail         | CN            |
|  31 | 8    | Japhet          | PH            |
|  32 | 7    | Abegail         | USA           |
|  33 | 7    | Abegail         | PH            |
|  34 | 8    | Abegail         | CN            |
+-----+------+-----------------+---------------+
```

I created a pivot and a join

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Procedure5]
as
SELECT *
FROM Cus S
   INNER JOIN (
      SELECT *
      FROM
         (SELECT * FROM Cus2) I
         PIVOT (Max(I.Name) FOR I.Country IN (PH, CN, USA)) P
   ) I ON S.id = I.id
;
RETURN 0
```

But the output of it has 3 similar names how can I to do it that it will only show all the data in the same rows.

My desired result:

```
+----------+-----+--------+---------+--------+
|   Name   | Age |   PH   |   CN    |  USA   |
+----------+-----+--------+---------+--------+
| Reynaldo |  65 | Japhet | Abegail | Japhet |
+----------+-----+--------+---------+--------+
```

My current output:

```
+----------+-----+--------+---------+--------+
|   Name   | Age |   PH   |   CN    |  USA   |
+----------+-----+--------+---------+--------+
| Reynaldo |  65 |        |         | Japhet |
| Reynaldo |  65 |        | Abegail |        |
| Reynaldo |  65 | Japhet |         |        |
+----------+-----+--------+---------+--------+
```

Comment: Can you add some data samples from your two tables (in text in the post), and the expected result ?

Comment: why are you joining back the result of the pivoting to the table `Cus` ?

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: how about the sample data from Cus and Cus2 table ?

Comment: Do the joining first and the pivoting last.
Also have a look at the unpivoted result of the join before adding the pivot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Pivot query should probably look like this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT c.Name,
                c.Age,
                c2.Name [Name2],
                c2.Country
        FROM    Cus c
                INNER JOIN Cus2 c2 ON c.Id = c2.Id) t
        PIVOT   (
            MAX(Name2)
            FOR Country IN ([PH], [CN], [USA])
        ) p
```

When you write a pivot query, make sure you create a derived table, and only select the fields that you want to see in you final result, and that all columns have a distinct name

An alternative to PIVOT would be MAX(Case) expressions.  This may perform better than PIVOT.

```
SELECT  c.Name,
        c.Age,
        MAX(CASE WHEN c2.Country = 'PH' THEN c2.Name END) AS [PH],
        MAX(CASE WHEN c2.Country = 'CN' THEN c2.Name END) AS [CN],
        MAX(CASE WHEN c2.Country = 'USA' THEN c2.Name END) AS [USA]
FROM    Cus c
        INNER JOIN Cus2 c2 ON c.Id = c2.Id
GROUP BY c.Name,
        c.Age
```

Comment: You're welcome.. You were really close, but when you use `Select *` in a pivot query you usually get too much information.. `(SELECT Id, Name, Country FROM Cus2)` inside your inner join would have given you close to what you wanted

Comment: @JaimeD77 Noted. Thanks, Bro. Commended you on this.